# Trouble drawing to screen in pygame using group

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having a problem, whereby calling a variable all_sprites as a pygame.Group() does not return any values, and I cannot work out why.

```
class game:

def __init__(self):
    pg.init()
    self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((screenwidth, screenheight))
    pg.display.set_caption("Gammee")
    self.clock = pg.time.Clock()



def run(self):

    while True:
        self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
        self.events()
        self.update()
        self.draw()

def new(self):
    self.othersprites = pg.sprite.Group()

def draw(self):
    self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)

    self.othersprites.draw(self.screen)

    pg.display.flip()

def quit(self):
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()

def update(self):
    self.othersprites.update()

def events(self):

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            self.quit()
g = game()

while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
```

this is the code for the game

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self, game, x, y):

    self.groups = game.all_sprites
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    self.game = game
    self.image = pg.Surface((30, 30), SRCALPHA)
    self.image.fill(YELLOW)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    self.vx, self.vy = 0, 0
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def get_keys(self):
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
        self.vx = -PLAYER_SPEED
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
        self.vx = PLAYER_SPEED
    if keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
        self.vy = -PLAYER_SPEED
    if keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
        self.vy = PLAYER_SPEED
    if len(keys) != 0:
        self.vx *= 0.9
        self.vy *= 0.9

def update(self):
    self.get_keys()
    self.x += self.vx * self.game.dt
    self.y += self.vy * self.game.dt
    self.rect.x = self.x
    self.rect.y = self.y
```

however nothing is drawn to the scree. I have also tested by putting

```
for sprite in self.all_sprites:
    print(sprite)
```

which used to output info on the sprite, but now does nothing,

any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you maybe forget to instantiate the `Player`? The code is not sufficient to find the error, so please edit your question and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated the question to include the full game code. For instantiating the player, I must be wrong in assuming iit is automatically instantiated when it is added to the group?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of the `Player` in the `new` method of the `game` class. Also, the sprite group is called `othersprites` in the `game` class and `all_sprites` in the `Player` class, but the names have to match.

```
class game:

    def new(self):
        self.othersprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        # This is how you create an instance/object.
        self.player = Player(self, 200, 300)


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.othersprites
```

I think it would be nicer and simpler to add the `self.player` sprite to `self.othersprites` in the new method instead of passing the whole `game` instance to the player.

```
class game:

    def new(self):
        self.othersprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(200, 300)
        self.othersprites.add(self.player)
```

Comment: BTW, classes should have upper + camelcase names, e.g. `class GameCharacter`, and lowercase with underscores (snake_case) is for functions/methods and variables, e.g. `a_variable_name`.